# 'Default value for binding' for uniqueidentifier in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, default-value, uniqueidentifier

I would like to set `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` as default value for a `uniqueidentifier` column. But I get the following error `Error validating the default for column 'MyID'`. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
create table #t
(
u uniqueidentifier default ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
)
```

works for me. Are you missing single quote marks around the literal?

This would be unusual though as generally these columns contain unique values.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively

```
CREATE TABLE #t(
 u uniqueidentifier DEFAULT (CAST(0x0 AS uniqueidentifier))
)
```